# Problem with Dependency Property and PropertyChangedCallback in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

In my `CustomControl`, I have a `View` dependency property that is set by the outer control using a view model. When this property is set, the `Refresh` method is triggered and the `View` is rendered. This works as expected. However, I would also like the `Refresh` method to be triggered when a property of the `View` is changed. Is this the standard way of handling this situation, or should I define a public `Refresh()` method on the control and call it from outside? Can I use commanding to achieve this? Any guidance on the correct approach would be appreciated.

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
        "View", typeof(View),
        typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(Refresh)
     );


  public View View
  {
     get => (View)GetValue(ViewProperty);
     set => SetValue(ViewProperty, value);
  }

  private static void Refresh(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     // 
     MessageBox.Show("Refreshed!");
  }

   public sealed class View : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      private bool m_isDirty;

      public bool IsDirty
      {
         get => m_isDirty;
         set
         {
            m_isDirty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook up an event handler for the `PropertyChanged` event of the `View` in your callback:

```
private static void Refresh(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Refreshed!");

    View newView = e.NewValue as View;
    if (newView != null)
        newView.PropertyChanged += NewView_PropertyChanged;

    View oldView = e.OldValue as View;
    if (oldView != null)
        oldView.PropertyChanged -= NewView_PropertyChanged;
}

private static void NewView_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    View view = (View)sender;
    //view updated...
}
```

Comment: Sounds a reasonable solution. Thank you. But then it will fire on every property change in View! And I do not want to hard-code the property name here! Isn't it possible to have some Refresh() method in the Control and a mechansim so that I can force it to execute via binding from outside?

Comment: It will fire whenever the view fires the PropertyChanged event. What property name are you referring to?

Comment: My View may have other properties that raise OnPropertyChanged like Name, etc. I only want change in a specific property of View to trigger the Refresh() on CustomControl. What I want is a kind of mechansim in CustomControl so that I can bind to my ViewModel outside the Control.

Comment: Maybe I should have a boolean RefreshRequested DP in CustomControl and bind it to imy view model outside the control as well?

Comment: Either check the name of the property that raised the event in the control or raise another event in View.

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer.